# Android Vertical View Pager with card stack

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-pagetransformer

I am trying to implement a vertical swipeable `ViewPager` with stack of cards like appearance.

I am able to achieve VerticalViewPager using `ViewPager.PageTransformer` and swapping the touch points. 
I am getting following card appearance - 
[image]

I want to achieve following appearance - 
[image]

How can I achieve this effect? 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi, did you found a solution for this question?

Comment: No I couldn't find the solution to it. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Can you out your whole code? So, We I can try it.

Comment: Hey did you already find something?

Answer (score 7):

In order to achieve this vertical View Pager **without any library dependency**
You can follow the steps below :

1. In your **activity_main.xml**

   ```
   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="600dp"
       android:id="@+id/viewpager">
   </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
   ```
2. In your **viewpager_contents.xml**

> You can create the design that you want according to the above
>   picture.

3. Create the **adapter** and **model class** to hold the data.

4.In **MainActivity.java**, after setting the adapter and the pageTransformer add the following code.

```
private class ViewPagerStack implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
    @Override
    public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
        if (position >= 0) {
            page.setScaleX(0.7f - 0.05f * position);
            page.setScaleY(0.7f);
            page.setTranslationX(-page.getWidth() * position);
            page.setTranslationY(30 * position);
        }
    }
}
```

For detailed reference you can watch this video:
[**CLICK HERE**](https://youtu.be/eK8fo-Eznw4)

Hope you will get the output what you needed!!

Answer (score 1):

none of the above solutions worked for me peroperly. 
this is my solution :

**My PageTransformer class :**

```
class ViewPagerCardTransformer : ViewPager.PageTransformer {
  override fun transformPage(page: View, position: Float) {
    if (position >= 0) {
      page.scaleX = 0.9f - 0.05f * position
      page.scaleY = 0.9f
      page.alpha = 1f - 0.3f * position
      page.translationX = -page.width * position
      page.translationY = -30 * position
    } else {
      page.alpha = 1 + 0.3f * position
      page.scaleX = 0.9f + 0.05f * position
      page.scaleY = 0.9f
      page.translationX = page.width * position
      page.translationY = 30 * position
    }
  }
}
```

**code in my fragment :**

```
val adapter = MyPagerAdapter(pageItems)
viewPager.adapter = adapter
/*below line will increase the number of cards stacked on top of 
each other it is set to 1 by default. don't increase it too much as you
will end up with too much view page items in your memory
*/
mDaysViewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 3 
viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, ViewPagerCardTransformer())
```

Comment: Asome thanks for the answer, How to do when user swipe left zoom in and fade out and swipe right zoom out fade in the card ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm Using this code for vertical card view stack

https://github.com/AndroidDeveloper98/StackViewPager

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use [the SwipeStack library](https://github.com/flschweiger/SwipeStack). It does exactly what you want - it is basically a viewgroup that inflates views based on your adapter implementation, placing them one on top of the other.

Answer (score 0):

The magic is here https://github.com/yuyakaido/CardStackView. You can easily custom what you want. Happy coding :)