# How to implement a card stack view in android that can be expanded into a list view (Similar to iOS group notifications)

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation

I want to implement a card stack view in android that can be expanded into a list view (Similar to iOS group notifications). I tried many libraries most of them are tinder like style (Swipe cards that cannot be expanded into list view). This is not a duplicate question most questions are for tinder like style.

Collapsed State,

[image: Collapsed Card Stack View]

Expanded State,

[image: Expanded Card Stack View]

**First approach**

I tried https://github.com/yuyakaido/CardStackView but but I couldn't get to display the cards that appearing behind using

```
CardStackLayoutManager.setStackFrom(StackFrom.Top)
```

Then again this library does not support expanding into a list view.

**Second approach**

Then I decided to implement custom view using view pager,

[Android Vertical View Pager with card stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40110483/android-vertical-view-pager-with-card-stack)

https://youtu.be/eK8fo-Eznw4

Now I'm able to display smaller cards that's appearing behind. But trying to figure out how to animate it to a list view when onClick.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey! I am implementing same thing on my app but I have one issue which is related to leftOverlay and right overlay. I didn't find any method to set the left overlay and right overlay.

Comment: @channae Did you find anything useful on this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use my library which resembles the iOS notifications behavior.

[image: StackExpandableView]

It is available in the following link https://github.com/fabiosassu/StackExpandableView.

Comment: Wonderful library. Exactly what am looking for. Thank u. ❤️

Comment: Is there a way to do the same animation with the recycler-view list.